# wxPython button changes text on panel

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to get a button press change the text on the panel but from a different function.

Ex:

```
status=wx.StaticText(panel,label="Yes",pos=(95,5),size=(50,20))
change=wx.Button(panel,label="Change",pos=(115,45),size=(50,20))
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.changed, change)
def changed(self,event):
 have it change the label to "no".
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.status.SetLabel`:

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size = (200, -1))
        self.state = 'Yes'
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self) 
        self.status = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label = self.state,
                               pos = (95, 5), size = (50, 20))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label = 'Change',
                                pos = (115, 45), size = (50, 20))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.changed, self.button)
    def changed(self, event):
        self.state = 'Yes' if self.state == 'No' else 'No'
        self.status.SetLabel(self.state)             

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, "Hello")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```